# IIS - Acesso negado a diretório

Tags: c#, wcf, asp, iis

Estou utilizando windows server 2008 e IIS 6.1, tenho um serviço que precisa acessar arquivos em um determinado diretório, mas não tenho acesso.

O que preciso configurar para obter acesso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de adicionar `Administrator` como o usuário, a aplicação diz que o diretório não existe.

```
    List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();

    if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\MovieCollector\PacotesSerializados"))
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dataFilePath))
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
            files.Add(fileInfo);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(dataFilePath+ " não lexiste");
    }

    files.Sort((x, y) => y.CreationTime.CompareTo(x.CreationTime));

    if (files.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Lista vazia");
    }
```

Comment: Se você tem algum usuário que tenha acesso a esse diretório, você pode dar permissão ao usuário que executa no IIS. Ou ainda não tenho certeza se é assim que funciona nessa versão do IIS, mas você pode definir o usuário que você quer conectar seu aplicativo no IIS, no IIS8 é a opção "Conectar como...", então ali defina um usuário com os privilégios no diretório em questão. (Talvez seja uma opção similar (Não tenho um IIS 6.1, para testar))

Comment: Adicionei `Administrator` como o usuário, mas diz que o diretório não existe. Adicionei uma imagem que mostra o erro no cliente e o diretório no servidor.

Comment: Qual o código executado para gerar a exceção indicada?

Comment: Adicionado o código utilizado para recuperar os arquivos.

Comment: Já experimentou adicionar o grupo `everyone` com leitura e escrita nesse diretório?

Answer (score 2):

Italo você já deu permissão total para o usuário IIS_IUSRS na pasta PacotesSerializados. Veja também se existe o Tipo de MIME .xml ou extensão utilizada no IIS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]